# innerHeight() conflicting in chrome?

Tags: jquery, css

CSS Code:

```
#jpspm {
    position: relative;
    top: -83px;
    left: -1px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 64px;
    padding-right: 63px;
    width: 563px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block; 
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
var jp_con = jQuery('#jpspm').innerHeight();
console.log('InnerHeight:' + jp_con);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xzexn/

in firefox and explorer it works fine, but in Chrome it gives difference, help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the differences between the browsers existing in this jsfiddle example too? http://jsfiddle.net/xzexn/

Comment: I get `26` in Fx8 *and* Chrome.

Comment: I suppose, that the innerHeight get manipulated by things like font-size. Maybe the font sizes (or any other output setting) is different in your chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client's `innerHeight` can vary pretty wildly. While jensgram did alright in the comments, I got `26` in Chrome and `6` in Firefox.

Keep in mind that `innerHeight` is also not reliably cross-browser *and* not as broadly useful as `clientHeight`. From [dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljknuajj.php):

> The innerHeight property is rarely useful, because scrollbars are not
>   part of the document working area. Use the cross-browser clientHeight
>   property of the html element instead. It returns the height of the
>   browser's client area without the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: i were trying if made possible somehow cause i am working on joomla but i thing your give a right way..